# Should I apply anti-seize to the back of brake rotors?

Tags: brakes

In regards to changing brake rotors:

As I see in many youtube videos, it could be a bit of a challenge to remove old brake rotors. They can stuck.

Is it a good idea to add some anti-seize compound to the back of rotors during the installation, so it will be easy to remove them later?

[image: Rotor]

Comment: I always apply a thin coat.

Answer (score 2):

WARNING .... POR is a great way to weld your rotors to the hub.

You will need a Jack Hammer to get your rotors off.

Anti Seize is without a doubt the ticket for this application.

I would rather put the anti seize on the hub between the studs where the hub contacts the back of the rotor.  This takes the guesswork out of where to apply it on the rotor!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that anti-seize compound is the way to go here. There's no harm in applying a little, but I wonder if it is the right compound for the job.

Anti-seize compound is usually to prevent hot metal parts from fusing together due to heat.

However, brake discs will typically get stuck due to rust, so the proper remedy would be to minimize or prevent the surface of the rotor from exposure to water or moisture.

To this effect, I'd imagine it is more effective to apply a coat of high-temp paint to the mating surface of the rotor prior to installation than to apply anti-seize compound, since (I expect) moisture can still make its way in past the anti-seize compound.

Comment: Surely you still have a layer of soft metal (copper) between the two surfaces, whether rust forms or the grease gets burnt away by heat from braking.  I admit I have never tried painting them, but I also have never had problems removing  rotors many years after applying a thin coat of anti-seize compound.

Comment: @HandyHowie : I'm not saying that anti-seize won't work, but do want to draw attention to the fact that it may not be the best fit. Nor is it the only solution to avoid rust-related seizures. Also, this answer is meant to be a possible option as opposed to the final word on the subject.

Comment: Also, @Zaid, I don't think I'd use paint in this particular area, either. I think it would have a propensity to bond the metal together, even better than rust would. A rust inhibitor (like POR15) would absolutely *weld* the rotor to the hub. I don't think minor amounts of anti-seize would cause issues. it's larger amounts which might get into your brakes if flung out which would cause issues. Just things to think about.

Comment: I dunno about painting the mating surface, cuz you want to clean it off "next time" with brake cleaner, and brake cleaner says to not use on painted surfaces?? :)